# Mongoose Middleware modifying to working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, mongoose, middleware

I am trying to add a uuid to every model before it is saved. As far as I can tell, my code it right(based on the first example on [this page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html)), but the property is not saved.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var uuid = require("node-uuid");

var siteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true
    }
});

siteSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    console.log(this);
    this.uuid = uuid.v4();
    console.log(this);
    next();
});

var siteModel = module.exports = mongoose.model("Site", siteSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you are trying to save does not exist in the schema, you need to define it or make it not strict.

So one approach to what you are doing:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    uuid = require("node-uuid");


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var demoSchema = new Schema({
  uuid: String,
});

demoSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  this.uuid = uuid.v4();
  next();
});


var Demo = mongoose.model( "Demo", demoSchema, "demo" );

var demo = new Demo();

demo.save(function(err,demo) {

  console.log( demo );

});
```

Where there is another field for uuid:

```
{ __v: 0,
  uuid: 'b55db0de-7b0e-4d15-854c-90bb49bd1463',
  _id: 53b242a760ca971e30a9349c }
```

Or you could use the [mongoose-uuid](https://github.com/dlamp/mongoose-uuid) plugin instead:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    uuid = require("mongoose-uuid");


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var demoSchema = new Schema({},{ _id: false});

demoSchema.plugin(uuid.plugin, "Demo");

var Demo = mongoose.model( "Demo", demoSchema, "demo" );

var demo = new Demo();

demo.save(function(err,demo) {

  console.log( demo );

});
```

The places the uuid in the `_id` field:

```
{ __v: 0, _id: '82bc7a00-00dd-11e4-a63a-4373a4cdbe8c' }
```

Comment: Awesome. Thats exactly what it was. I wonder if there is any downside to using uuids as the id?

Comment: @giodamelio If they are the random type then they are not "monotonic" as is the indented purpose of the default ObjectId type. Then again randomness can be useful for sharding if a random distribution is what you are after. Both of these are implemented as strings for the key, which may or may not be a benefit/hinderance. It just depends on your case.